# How to write a Perl script to check x number of columns to print a value in another line for each returned value

Tags: perl, loops, if-statement, foreach

I have data (IP addresses) in a CSV file that will be columns 9-13.  If there aren't values in the other columns, then by default it should just print out what is in column 9. There is an output file that will print a set of values and the value of column 9 (and through 13 if a value exist) concatenated with a static value to create an alias value.  My question is, how would you do this efficiently?  I have this code that works:

```
my $alias0= "ComponentAliases=['ComputerSystem:$columns[9]'];\n";
my $alias1= "ComponentAliases=['ComputerSystem:$columns[9]','ComputerSystem:$columns[10]'];\n";
my $alias2= "ComponentAliases=['ComputerSystem:$columns[9]','ComputerSystem:$columns[10]','ComputerSystem:$columns[11]'];\n";


        print BAROC "ComputerSystem;\n";
        if(($columns[11] != '')&&($columns[10] != '')) {  print BAROC $alias2 }
        elsif(($columns[11] == '')&&($columns[10] != '')) {  print BAROC $alias1 }
        elsif(($columns[11] == '')&&($columns[10] == '')) { print BAROC $alias0 }
```

This works to do what I want it to do, but there is a chance the CSV file will have values in columns 9-13 or 9-11, etc.  Easily I think statically writing this will be fine, but I would like to do it efficiently as well as understand and always apply best practices. I'm new to scripting Perl, but continually am drawn to it to solve problems at work. Suggestions?

This is the output, btw:

```
ComponentAliases=['ComputerSystem:10.1.0.225','ComputerSystem:10.200.252.77','ComputerSystem:10.100.252.77'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv_in = Text::CSV_XS->new
    or die Text::CSV_XS->error_diag;

my $csv_out = Text::CSV_XS->new({
    always_quote => 1,
    quote_char => q{'},
}) or die Text::CSV_XS->error_diag;

while (my $row = $csv_in->getline(\*DATA)) {
    my @aliases = map "ComputerSystem:$_",
                  grep defined && length, @$row[9 .. 13];
    if ($csv_out->combine(@aliases)) {
        printf "ComponentAliases=[%s];\n", $csv_out->string;
    }
}

__DATA__
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10.1.0.225,10.200.252.77,,,,,,,
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10.1.0.225,10.200.252.77,10.100.252.77,,,,,
```

Output:

```
C:\temp> gn
ComponentAliases=['ComputerSystem:10.1.0.225','ComputerSystem:10.200.252.77'];
ComponentAliases=['ComputerSystem:10.1.0.225','ComputerSystem:10.200.252.77','Co
mputerSystem:10.100.252.77'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Efficiently now means *maintainable*. Trying to save a command or two isn't going to save you to much time. In fact, it might actually make the program more inefficient if the compiler can't figure out what you're doing.

What is important is readability. Get rid of the `$alias` stuff. It simply makes it harder to see what your code is doing, and you could end up with all sorts of side effects doing stuff like this.

The lack of white space also makes your code much more difficult to figure out too. Once I reformatted your code, I immediately spotted an error. You did this:

```
if ( ($columns[11] != '') && ($columns[10] != '') )
```

However, this is a *string comparison*. You need to do this:

```
if ( ( $columns[11] ne '' ) && ( $columns[10] ne '' ) ) {
```

Or, you could simplify it even further:

```
if ( not $column[10] and not $column[11] ) {
```

This makes it very clear what you're looking for, and will work whether the columns contain a numeric zero, a null string, or are undefined.

This code snippet is using your logic, but I take advantage of the fact that `print` doesn't automatically add a `\n` at the end of the string. I simply continue building upon the line:

```
if ( $columns[9] ) {
    print BAROC "ComputerSystem;\n";
    print BAROC "ComponentAliases=['ComputerSystem:$columns[9]'";

    if ( $columns[10] ) {
         print BAROC ",ComputerSystem:$columns[10]";
    }
    if ( $columns[11] )  {
        print BAROC ",ComputerSystem:$columns[11]";
    }
    print BAROC "];\n";
}
```

You mentioned that you might need columns 9 to 13 if these columns had data in them. Why not use a loop?

```
if ( $#columns >= 9 ) {    #There are at least nine columns
    print BAROC "ComputerSystem;\n";
    print BAROC "ComponentAliases=[ComputerSystem:$columns[9]";

    for my $column ( (10..$#columns) ) {
       last if not $column[$column];
       print BAROC ",ComputerSystem:$columns[$columns];
    }
    print BAROC "];\n";
}
```

If given more time, I'm sure I could clean up the logic a bit more. But, this will work whether there are 9, 10, 11, or 43 columns with data.

Answer (score 0):

One liner (not so elegant, but somehow I like it):

```
print "ComponentAliases=[".join(",",map {"'ComputerSystem:$_'"} grep {$_ ne ""} @columns[9-13])."]\n";
```

Or if you prefer the same code in a more understandable way:

```
print(  
        "ComponentAliases=[",
        join(
            ",",
            map(    
                "'ComputerSystem:$_'",
                grep (
                        $_ ne "",
                        @columns[9-13]
                     )
               )
            ),  
        "]\n"
     );
```